# Android Studio Firebase problem: nothing is displayed

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm creating an app with 3 other people, I have my own branch on Github. I have a recycler view in layout folder and 3 files for my products: ProductListActivity, ProductModel and ProductAdapter. When I build, I have 0 error and I am connected to the correct firebase on Android Studio but absolutly nothing is displayed in my app, there is my code:

```
class ProductListActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var dbref : DatabaseReference
private lateinit var productRecyclerView: RecyclerView
private lateinit var productArrayList: ArrayList<ProductModel>

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.fil_actu)

    productRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.market_list)
    productRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    productRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)

    productArrayList = arrayListOf<ProductModel>()

    getProductData()
}

private fun getProductData() {

    // connexion avec la base de données sur la table 'Products'
    dbref = Firebase.database("https://tierchaser-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/").getReference("Products")

    dbref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                Toast.makeText(this@ProductListActivity, "snapshot exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                // boucle sur chaque produit qui sera contenu dans 'productSnapshot'
                for (productSnapshot in snapshot.children) {

                    Toast.makeText(this@ProductListActivity, "bdd lu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    // on récupère le produit actuel
                    val product = productSnapshot.getValue(ProductModel::class.java)
                    // on le met dans 'productArrayList'
                    productArrayList.add(product!!)
                }
                productRecyclerView.adapter = ProductAdapter(productArrayList)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this@ProductListActivity, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(this@ProductListActivity, error.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

    })

}
```

}

```
class ProductAdapter(private val productList : ArrayList<ProductModel>) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ProductViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ProductViewHolder {

    val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.product_item,
    parent, false)
    return ProductViewHolder(itemView)

}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProductViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val currentItem = productList[position]

    holder.address.text = currentItem.address
    holder.city.text = currentItem.city
    holder.date.text = currentItem.date
    //Glide.with(holder.itemView).load(currentItem.imageUrl).into(holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.logoLocation))
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return productList.size
}

class ProductViewHolder(itemView : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    val address : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.address)
    val city : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.city)
    val date : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date)
    //val image : ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productImage)

}
```

}

```
data class ProductModel (var address : String ?= null, var city : String ?= null, var date : String ?= null)
```

I have all the required imports by the way, and the Toasts don't show up either

Thank you for help !

Comment: Is any of the Toast messages, display something?

Comment: If none of toast is being shown, then are you sure you have called `getProductData`?

Comment: No I have any Toast that display something.., and yes I call getProductData in onCreate function